# Find $(a>0),b\in \mathbb{R}$ so that $L=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x^a(x^2(\sqrt[3]{1+x^3}-x)-b)$ exists and $L\neq0$

Tags: calculus, limits

If we know that the limit exist iff

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty^-}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty^+}f(x)=L$$

can we form a system of equations? How to solve left and right limit, and is there any condition for $L\neq 0$?

Comment: Are you sure $a\neq 0$ ?

Comment: @ Mann That is the given condition.

Comment: @mathlove They are  given conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how the limit can be written for sufficiently large $x$.

$L=x^a\left(x^2\left(x\times\left(1+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)^{1/3}-x\right)-b\right)$

$L=x^a\left(x^3\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)^{1/3}-1\right)-b\right)$

Expanding binomially the term $\left(1+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)^{1/3}-1=\frac{1}{3x^3}$

Gives

$L=x^a\left(\frac{1}{3}-b\right)$

Which exists and not equal $0$. Only if $a=0$? if $\pm\infty$ are not considered and $b\neq \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: How did you expand $(1+\frac{1}{x^3})^\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: Binomial theorem for small $v$ where $(1+v)^a=1+av$